# Rest kit RKMappingOperation app is getting crash very rarely.

Tags: ios, restkit

In my app i am using Restkit.I am saving huge number of data using core data.while mapping all the data using rest kit, I am getting crash in **RKMappingOperation.m line 719 -[RKMappingOperation applyAttributeMapping:withValue:]** very rare scenario in mobile device. In simulator when i run for the first time its getting crash. can anyone help me to solve this issue?